# How to read response with authorization code that is sent to a custom redirect uri?

Tags: c#, xamarin, google-oauth

I would like to know, how one can get the response containing auth code from google, when the redirect uri is a custom uri.

This is the code that i use. I open the url in a browser.( currently testing in ios-simulator)

```
var url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?";
string scope = "email%20profile";
string redirect_uri = "com.companyname.exampleauth://";
string response_type = "code";
string access_type = "offline";
```

Once user allows the app, it goes back to the app! but, how do i get the response with code?

Answer (score 0):

In the info.plist under the Advance tab you'll see URL Types. Register your app there. Use your bundle identifer as the Identifier, your redirect_uri as the URL scheme and editor for role.

The AppDelegate will get called when the user is done. Heres an example:

```
    public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
    {
        if (url.Scheme == "yourScheme") {

            var queryParams = url.Query.Split('&');

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```